# HTML element does not go as full width

Tags: html, css

So I have a code for a website that uses HTML and CSS but I have a problem with CSS.

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>TEST</h2>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a href="todo.html" class="notactive"><img src="todo.png"></a>
        <a href="home.html" class="active"><img src="home.png"></a>
        <a href="info.html" class="notactive"><img src="info.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #222222;
  color: black;
}
```

This is my result:
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8HV6.png)

It works and all, but if you look at the bottom left (at the menu), it isn't fully covered. I have tried many ways to cover it, but I can't seem to get it right.

Any ideas? Appreciated if you explain it to me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most major browsers apply a margin on the `body`, thus causing the footer not expanding to the viewport's full width.

To get rid of the margin, applying `margin: 0` to `body`:

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #222222;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>TEST</h2>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a href="todo.html" class="notactive"><img src="todo.png"></a>
        <a href="home.html" class="active"><img src="home.png"></a>
        <a href="info.html" class="notactive"><img src="info.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked thanks. Also I have a question to ask. Shouldn't the margin of the body automatically be set to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `left : 0;`

```
.navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also reduce that type of error by just adding this code at the top.

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```